# Android Ustream share

Tags: android, flash

Am trying to create an application that will stream a tv station live from ustream but nothing seems to work.The page is loading no video.Below is my code

```
package i;

import i.standard.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

 public class HTML5WebView extends WebView {

private Context                             mContext;
private MyWebChromeClient                   mWebChromeClient;
private View                                mCustomView;
private FrameLayout                         mCustomViewContainer;
private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback  mCustomViewCallback;

private FrameLayout                         mContentView;
private FrameLayout                         mBrowserFrameLayout;
private FrameLayout                         mLayout;

static final String LOGTAG = "HTML5WebView";

private void init(Context context) {
    mContext = context;     
    Activity a = (Activity) mContext;

    mLayout = new FrameLayout(context);

    mBrowserFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(a).inflate(R.layout.custom_screen, null);
    mContentView = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) mBrowserFrameLayout.findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_custom_content);

    mLayout.addView(mBrowserFrameLayout, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);

    mWebChromeClient = new MyWebChromeClient();
    setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

    setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    // Configure the webview
    WebSettings s = getSettings();
    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    s.setSavePassword(true);
    s.setSaveFormData(true);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    // enable navigator.geolocation 
    s.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    s.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/org.itri.html5webview/databases/");

    // enable Web Storage: localStorage, sessionStorage
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    mContentView.addView(this);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public HTML5WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

public FrameLayout getLayout() {
    return mLayout;
}

public boolean inCustomView() {
    return (mCustomView != null);
}

public void hideCustomView() {
    mWebChromeClient.onHideCustomView();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if ((mCustomView == null) && canGoBack()){
            goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
    private Bitmap      mDefaultVideoPoster;
    private View        mVideoProgressView;

    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
    {
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on ShowCustomView");
        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }

        mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
        mCustomView = view;
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {

        if (mCustomView == null)
            return;        

        // Hide the custom view.
        mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Remove the custom view from its container.
        mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
        mCustomView = null;
        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

        HTML5WebView.this.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "set it to webVew");
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getDefaultVideoPoster");    
        if (mDefaultVideoPoster == null) {
            mDefaultVideoPoster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                    getResources(), R.drawable.default_video_poster);
        }
        return mDefaultVideoPoster;
    }

    @Override
    public View getVideoLoadingProgressView() {
        //Log.i(LOGTAG, "here in on getVideoLoadingPregressView");

        if (mVideoProgressView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            mVideoProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_loading_progress, null);               
        }
        return mVideoProgressView; 
    }

     @Override
     public void onReceivedTitle(WebView view, String title) {
        ((Activity) mContext).setTitle(title);
     }

     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
         ((Activity) mContext).getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, newProgress*100);
     }

     @Override
     public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
         callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
     }
}

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading: "+url);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

static final FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS =
    new FrameLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

}

I created a class to implement the above html5..check the code below
    package i;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class TestHTML5WebView extends Activity {

HTML5WebView mWebView;

String url="http://www.ustream.tv/embed/10464044";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mWebView = new HTML5WebView(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
           mWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);//http://www.ustream.tv/KTNKENYALIVE///http://youtu.be/Mmry0Bdj9Vg
    } else {    
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }

    setContentView(mWebView.getLayout());
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mWebView.saveState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mWebView.stopLoading();
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        if (mWebView.inCustomView()) {
            mWebView.hideCustomView();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}